# Displaying array items in an irregular grid format

Tags: c#, .net, xna

I have an array of fixed sized images that I want to display in a grid in the following format, with the lines containing seven items centered relative to the line above it.

```
12345678
1234567
12345678
1234567
```

I'm unsure as to how I can iterate through the array to achieve this. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You don't say whether you are developing a Windows Forms application or a Web Site? Or maybe something else? Have you tried anything already?

Comment: Also... In what format is your array? Is it two-dimensional? How are the 'blank' items at the end (ie the missing 8th element) represented? What are the upper and lower limits on how many elements can appear in one row?

Comment: You want just the lines containing seven items centred? Or them all centred? Is this a console app or GUI? Does the array only contain 7 and 8 character entries?

Comment: Sorry for being vague. I'm trying to create a game in XNA. The array is two dimensional. I hadn't considered adding a blank 8th item at the end. Each row can contain between 0 and 8 items. I would just like the lines with 7 items centered relative to the row above it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I ended up with, using an idea from El Ronnoco

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 7; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j <= 7; j++)
                {
                    grid[i, j].posX = i * 50;
                    grid[i, j].posY = j * 50;                      

                    if (i % 2 > 0)
                    {
                        grid[i, j].posY += 25;

                        if (j == 7)
                        {
                            //remove grid[i, j] from array/sight
                        }
                }
            }
```

Thank you for all the answers and help.

Answer (score 2):

You wouldn't be able to accomplish this in the console, because the text is rendered without any styling information.  Without a space in front, it looks like you wrote it.  If you put a space before the text, it will look right aligned.  There is no such thing as a half-space in the console.

If you were to render it in something more rich, such as html, this would be accomplishable.

Comment: The text in the code block was only supposed to represent the format I wanted to display the array items in. I'm actually working with images. I've edited the question to make it more clear. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a grid; the data isn't being shown in tabular form. If you're working with ASP.NET, use a server-side repeater with a `Panel` wrapped around each row, and set the panel's `HorizontalAlign="Center"` where appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with XNA so I don't know if you are blessed with control windows you can place around the screen or have to perform all drawing manually.  Irrespective, the centering logic is the same and can be adapted:

As text has to be placed by the coordinate of the top-left corner within the containing box (be it the screen, an enclosing panel or window, &c.) you need to perform the following calculation:

```
textLeft = (containerWidth - textWidth) / 2
```

To visualize this, it might be better to expand it:

```
textLeft = containerWidth / 2 - textWidth / 2
```

So, starting on the left side of the container (*x* of zero) you move half way across the container, then move back half the width of the text, thus placing half the text width either side of the centre line.